# Multiple auto-refresh data bindings in one page using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

One data binding works well and display automatic data but when I add another copying the same pattern of first, second gives error and do not work. So in below example if I do comment anyone, another do not work.

**HTML CODE**:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Price</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemsdisplay">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name" />
        <td data-bind="text: Price" />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="3" style="color:#06C">Stock Market Metal Rates</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: MetalDisplay">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name" />
        <td data-bind="text: Price" />
        <td data-bind="text: Dated" />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is my JS code**:

```
function GetProducts(handleData) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'form.php',
            type: "post",
            data: '',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                handleData(data);
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert('Failed');
            }
        });
}

function GetMetals(handleData) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'form2.php',
            type: "post",
            data: '',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                handleData(data);
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert('Failed');
            }
        });
}

$(function () {

  var ItemDisplayViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.itemsdisplay = ko.observableArray();

    self.update = function() {
        GetProducts(function(output){
            self.itemsdisplay.removeAll();
            $.each(output, function (i) {
                self.itemsdisplay.push(new product(output[i]));
            });
        }); 
    }
  };

  var MetalViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.MetalDisplay = ko.observableArray();

    self.update = function() {
        GetMetals(function(output){
            self.MetalDisplay.removeAll();
            $.each(output, function (i) {
                self.MetalDisplay.push(new metals(output[i]));
            });
        }); 
    }
  };

var ItemDisplayViewModel = new ItemDisplayViewModel();
window.setInterval(ItemDisplayViewModel.update,1000);
ko.applyBindings(ItemDisplayViewModel);

var MetalViewModel = new MetalViewModel();
window.setInterval(MetalViewModel.update,1000);
ko.applyBindings(MetalViewModel);

});
var product = function (data) {
    return {
        Name: ko.observable(data.Name),
        Price: ko.observable(data.Price)
    };
};
var metals = function (data) {
    return {
        Name: ko.observable(data.Name),
        Price: ko.observable(data.Price),
        Dated: ko.observable(data.Dated)
    };
};
```

Can anyone help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. 
Provide id for both the tables

```
     <table id="item">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Item Name</th><th>Price</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemsdisplay">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name" />
        <td data-bind="text: Price" />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="metal">
  <thead>
      <tr><th colspan="3" style="color:#06C">Stock Market Metal Rates</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: MetalDisplay">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name" />
        <td data-bind="text: Price" />
        <td data-bind="text: Dated" />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The modify your script to pass the table element to ko.applyBindings method as below.

```
var itemDisplayViewModel = new ItemDisplayViewModel();
var x = window.setInterval(itemDisplayViewModel.update,1000);
ko.applyBindings(itemDisplayViewModel,document.getElementById("item"));

var metalViewModel = new MetalViewModel();
var y = window.setInterval(metalViewModel.update,1000);
ko.applyBindings(metalViewModel, document.getElementById("metal"));
```

Please refer 'Activating knockout' section in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html - The part of text from the link given below.

*For example, ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId')). This restricts the activation to the element with ID someElementId and its descendants, which is useful if you want to have multiple view models and associate each with a different region of the page.*

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing does not work. you need to do it like this.

```
ko.applyBindings(ItemDisplayViewModel,document.getElementById('first_div_id'));
ko.applyBindings(MetalViewModel,document.getElementById('second_div_id'));
```

Or here is another method

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this
    self.Item = ko.observable(new ItemDisplayViewModel())
    self.Metal = ko.observable(new MetalViewModel())
} 

ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

And now

```
<table data-bind="with:Item"> 
.
.
.
</table> 

<table data-bind="with:Metal">  
.
.
.
</table>
```

And finally

```
window.setInterval(viewModel.Item().update, 1000);
window.setInterval(viewModel.Metal().update, 1000);
```

You can take a look at [this](http://raheelshan.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/knockoutjs-make-parent-and-child-structure-in-your-app/) post for better understanding.

Comment: thanks i say you go through the post and you will know a better way of handling things